# iptables route a few source ports to one destination port?

Tags: linux, iptables

Lets say I'm trying to use iptables to route all tcp traffic from ports 80,443,9090 to a signle port (8080).

How can I do it in a one iptables line?

I tried running this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/8 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 --dport 8081 -j NFQUEUE
```

but this is the error:

```
multiport: option "--source-ports" cannot be used together with "--destination-ports"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The application on the target port can detect the type of traffic?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of operation must be done in the `nat` table, in the chain `PREROUTING`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp \
  -m multiport --dports 80,443,9090 -j DNAT --to-destination :8080
```

Comment: Thanks! care to explain?

Comment: @toti What do you want explained? That is just knowlege that you have to have... It is mentioned in `man iptables-extensions` for the target `DNAT`, and this image may help: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg